# Chrome file upload bug: file name goes wrong when choose for the second time

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-upload, web

I am working on a simple web page with a file upload control:

```
<input type="file" name="file">
```

And when I test it, I find this strange bug: when I choose a file from disk for the second time, the file name will go wrong.

For example, when I choose `E:\tmp\123456789012345.jpg`, the value of the input will be `C:\fakepath\123456789012345.jpg`, which is correct. But then if I click the browse button again and choose file `E:\tmp\a.jpg`, the value of the input will become `C:\fakepath\45.jpg`, causing a file not found error afterwards.

After repeated test with different files, I find out that the bug occurs only when I choose a file with a longer file name, and then choose a shorter file name.

Also, the broken file name is a "suffix" of the longer file name (chosen at the first time), and `broken_file_name.length + correct_file_name.length == long_file_name - 4`.

An example case and corresponding console output:

```
// first, choose e:\tmp\123456789012345.jpg
>$('input[name="file"]').val()
<"C:\fakepath\123456789012345.jpg"
>$('input[name="file"]').val().length
<31

// then choose e:\tmp\a.jpg
>$('input[name="file"]').val()
<"C:\fakepath\45.jpg"  // should be "C:\fakepath\a.jpg"
>$('input[name="file"]').val().length
<18  // should be 17

// choose e:\tmp\123456789012345.jpg again, and then choose e:\tmp\ab.jpg
>$('input[name="file"]').val()
<"C:\fakepath\5.jpg"  // should be "C:\fakepath\ab.jpg"
>$('input[name="file"]').val().length
<17  // should be 18

// choose e:\tmp\123456789012345.jpg again, and then choose e:\tmp\abc.jpg
>$('input[name="file"]').val()
<"C:\fakepath\.jpg"  // should be "C:\fakepath\abc.jpg"
>$('input[name="file"]').val().length
<16  // should be 19
```

I tried searching this at Chromium issues list, and got nothing.

The bug occurs on Chrome 39, and disappears on Chrome 41. And IE works fine due to using real path on disk instead of "C:\fakepath".

Any ideas?

Comment: _“Any ideas?”_ –  about what? What appears to be a simple browser bug? Yes, those happen.

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure if it is a bug of Chrome or a bug of my code..

Comment: What code? If this is just a simple file upload field and nothing else – then where could you possible have messed this up?

Comment: @CBroe Well, that makes sense. :)